# How to determine if a custom Ufl is present in a Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

(Putting this up here as I couldn't find as the answer isn't on StackExchange yet and was driving me nuts. If you have a better answer I'll gladly accept it.)

I ran into an issue where our application needed to check for the presence of a UFL in a Crystal Report before attempting to print the report in order to both setup the database for the Ufl and to (in the future) warning the user when we start deprecating the UFL. What I needed was a method to determine if the report formulas called the UFL in question.

Comment: +1 While I have no idea about your question (or answer), it's always nice to see users post solutions that they came up with themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lay in the fact that while direct access to the forumlas used is not in the Report Document object, the raw text of the formulas is available in `ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields`. From there a text search can be performed to see if the Ufl name appears. I built a `ReportDocumentWrapper.cs` class that inherited from ReportDocument and added the following method:

```
public bool IsCustomUflPresent 
{ 
  get
  {
    return this.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Cast().Any(x => x.Text.Contains("CustomUfl("));
  }
}
```

While the check still takes less than a half-second on a report with 100+ fields text searches should never be considered performant, so be careful when using this on particularly massive reports!